# Electromagnetism as a $U(1)$-gauge theory

Tags: reference-request, characteristic-classes, gauge-theory

I would like to learn gauge theory, starting from the simplest case. I have heard that I should start with electromagnetism, which is just the $U(1)$-gauge theory. All the references I know are written for physics students.

Being familiar with bundle theory, it would be nice if I can start with a short exposition that explains electromagnetism **using the language of bundles, characteristic classes, curvatures, etc..** . Any relevant pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I like the lecture notes by José Figueroa-O'Farrill  https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/

Comment: It seems to be useful! I will grok the first 5 lectures soon.

Answer (score 4):

John Baez wrote a book called Gauge Fields, Knots, and Gravity.  I think it's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: His book is amazing indeed! But that book does not treat its readers as if they know bundle theory..

Answer (score 1):

I think a comprehensive reference here would be Naber's Topology, Geometry and Gauge fields ([Volume 1](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441972538), [Volume 2](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-7895-0)).

More specifically, Sections 0.2 of Volume 1 has a physical discussion of Maxwell's equations and Dirac monopoles, which is reformulated in differential-geometric language (i.e. principal bundles, connections, etc.) in Section 0.4.

Comment: Some other references in mathematical gauge theory would be [Haydys's notes](http://haydys.net/misc/IntroGaugeTheory_LectNotes.pdf) and [Debray's notes of a course by Daniel Freed](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/a.debray/lecture_notes/m392c_ADHM_notes.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The book "The Geometry of Physics: An Introduction", by Theodore Frankel is, despite its name, a fairly complete treatment.